# Very old dual coaxial TV outlet, how to fix it to connect to a modern TV?

Tags: diy, tv, coaxial

i've recently moved into an older updated apartment building and want to connect to the TV outlet but have a connection that i've never seen before. Can someone point me in the right direction of how this connection operates and or new connectors compatible to fix?

[image]

[image]

Comment: why do you want to connect it? ... what's at the other end of the cable?

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with that wall plate outlet. But the \$330\:\Omega\$ resistor is suggestive. Perhaps you can clarify. *Can you **exclude** the idea that this may be a connection to a rooftop antenna?*

Comment: yeah, that looks like the back of one of my 1950's tube radios: the 300 Ω "aerial" connector for the FM bands. I don't think you'll get anything that's useful to you, even if there still was the matching antenna at the other end of the cable (which potentially isn't coax, either, but a ladder line)

Comment: it is not a coaxial connector ... it is a twin-lead connector ... use one of these converters to connect a 75 ohm coaxial cable ... https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/8DUAAOSw~y9ZH1fU/s-l300.jpg ... cut off the spades off the spade lugs and jam the ends into the two holes ... connect a coaxial cable from the round threaded connector on the converter to your TV ... though I doubt that you will receive anything

Comment: @jsotola but OP wants to connect a *modern* TV to it. I don't think there's digital TV channels anywhere in the bands that these outlets were used for, 50 years ago?

Comment: Mick21, I think you'll need to make sure this is actually the TV outlet.

Comment: the channel master label strongly suggests that it is a TV outlet

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for the responses, just to confirm some Q's, @MarcusMüller yes the apartment was built circa 60's but alot has been updated within the building since then, except for the TV outlets! I believe previous owners used an adapter to get reception with that outlet but I would prefer to be using 21st century equipment.  My intention was to replace the outlet with a standard female co ax outlet and just put the cables into a Y splitter behind the plate, hoping the smart TV would not need the resistor and capacitor to get the signal to work. Would that fix my issue?

Comment: Something like these [Co ax Y splitter](https://www.ebay.com.au/i/233731430771?chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=705-139619-5960-0&mkcid=2&itemid=233731430771&targetid=921460872233&device=c&mktype=pla&googleloc=9070519&poi=&campaignid=10101785189&mkgroupid=102311926500&rlsatarget=pla-921460872233&abcId=9300368&merchantid=7364522&gclid=Cj0KCQiAkuP9BRCkARIsAKGLE8X3cg6jsAJ2QPCXqQQ-wgBpOe9YU-UVnyKGJ-aodXdc7eDXg8_iTyUaAiNhEALw_wcB) and this [Co ax outlet](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/171062260081?mkevt=1&mkcid=28&chn=ps)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this site belongs to DIY.SE

Answer (score 2):

that's a 300 ohm outlet for connecting ladder-line, it's best to replace it with a co-ax outlet.

it appears to also be a pass-through splitter, so if you need ther other TV outlet(s) to continure to work you'll need a splitter here too.